# MongoDB+Aggregation: effective way to 1) get results by a query 2) make analytics via aggregation on same results

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to get a filtered list of realties from DB (filter by price, location, etc.) and then show analytics table (made via Aggregation framework) showing min/max/avg price and total quantity of all realties. Simplified example of what I need at the end:

```
realties = [{_id: 1, price: 2500}, {_id: 1, price: 2500}, ... ];
stats = {total: 12500, max_price: 250000, min_price: 10000, avg_price: 150000};
```

What is the best way to do that? As I can see I have to make same query 2 times: 1st when I get paginated results from DB, and then - I have to put same conditions into "$match" in aggregation framework?:

```
realteis = db.collection.where({city: "NYC", type: 2, ...}).skip(100).limit(25)
stats = db.collection.aggregation({$match: {city: "NYC", type: 2, ...}, $group: {...}} )
```

So these are two almost identical queries to DB which doesn't seem very effective to me and I believe there's a better approach.

Is there a way to "chain" filtered results from 1st query to aggregation framework?

Or may be it's better to use some other tools? (but I need Mongo anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't a way to "chain" existing find() results into an aggregation framework job automatically. One approach would be to iterate through your find() results and insert each one into a new temporary collection. Then run the aggregation framework job against the temporary collection with the filtered results. That would certainly minimize the need to query the larger dataset twice.

Since the stats you're trying to compute are pretty straightforward, you could aks have your application code compute the total, min, max, and average in line.